# MS Access - count quantity of distinct pairs

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a dataset with two columns in MS Access. I'm trying to count, how many times each distinct pair can be found in dataset. For example,
the dataset:

[image]

and the result of counting should be:

[image]

I tried to apply the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Column1, Column2 FROM Dataset)
GROUP BY Column1, Column2
ORDER BY Number
```

Unfortunately it did not lead to success.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```sql
SELECT Column1, Column2, COUNT(*) AS Number 
FROM Dataset
GROUP BY Column1, Column2
```